# Método onclick de listview no funciona al retornar a la activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-listview

estoy trabajando en una app con firebase y me encontre con un detalle, en una de las secciones de la app la cuál comprende dos activities en la primera cargo una lista al dar tap a un elemento me lleva a la segunda activity sin problema, el detalle esta que cuando regreso de la segunda a la primera activity el listview de dicha activity ya no funciona como que la pantalla se congela. A continuación les dejo mi código usado en las dos activities mencionadas.

DirectorioEmpresas2.java

```
String id_categoria;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    ListView listSubCategorias;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView;
    TextView textViewMsgNoRegistros;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_directorio_empresas2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Subcategorías");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        id_categoria = extras.getString("id_categoria");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/cat_subcateg");
        listSubCategorias = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaSubCategorias);
        textViewMsgNoRegistros = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MsgNoRegistros);
        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView);
        listSubCategorias.setEmptyView(swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView);
        listSubCategorias.setAdapter(null);

        CargarSubCategorias();

        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                listSubCategorias.setAdapter(null);
                CargarSubCategorias();
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimaryDark,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                listSubCategorias.setAdapter(null);
                CargarSubCategorias();
                swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimaryDark,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        listSubCategorias.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                boolean enable = false;
                if (listSubCategorias != null && listSubCategorias.getChildCount() > 0) {
                    boolean firstItemVisible = listSubCategorias.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
                    boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = listSubCategorias.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
                    enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
                }
                swipeContainer.setEnabled(enable);
            }
        });

        listSubCategorias.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView id_subcategoria = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewIDSubCategoria);
                Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Empresas.class);
                objIndent.putExtra("id_categoria", id_categoria);
                objIndent.putExtra("id_subcategoria", id_subcategoria.getText().toString());
                startActivity(objIndent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void CargarSubCategorias()
    {
        showProgressDialog();
        Query query = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("id_categoria").equalTo(id_categoria);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final ArrayList<SubCategoriaEmpresa> subcategoriasList = new ArrayList<SubCategoriaEmpresa>();
                for (DataSnapshot subcategSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    SubCategoriaEmpresa subcategoria = subcategSnapshot.getValue(SubCategoriaEmpresa.class);
                    subcategoriasList.add(subcategoria);
                }

                if(subcategoriasList.size() > 0)
                {
                    AdapterSubCategorias adaptersubCat = new AdapterSubCategorias(DirectorioEmpresas2.this,subcategoriasList,getApplicationContext());
                    listSubCategorias.setAdapter(adaptersubCat);
                }
                hideProgressDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando información...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DirectorioEmpresas.class);
        startActivity(objIndent);
    }
```

Empresas.java

```
String id_categoria,id_subcategoria;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    ListView listaEmpresas;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView;
    TextView textViewMsgNoRegistros;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_empresas);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Empresas");
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        id_categoria = extras.getString("id_categoria");
        id_subcategoria = extras.getString("id_subcategoria");

        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/cat_empresas");
        listaEmpresas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaEmpresas);
        textViewMsgNoRegistros = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MsgNoRegistros);
        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView);
        listaEmpresas.setEmptyView(swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView);
        listaEmpresas.setAdapter(null);

        CargarEmpresas();

        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                listaEmpresas.setAdapter(null);
                CargarEmpresas();
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimaryDark,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                listaEmpresas.setAdapter(null);
                CargarEmpresas();
                swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimaryDark,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        listaEmpresas.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                boolean enable = false;
                if (listaEmpresas != null && listaEmpresas.getChildCount() > 0) {
                    boolean firstItemVisible = listaEmpresas.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
                    boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = listaEmpresas.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
                    enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible;
                }
                swipeContainer.setEnabled(enable);
            }
        });
    }

    private void CargarEmpresas()
    {
        showProgressDialog();
        Query query = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("id_categoria").equalTo(id_categoria);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final ArrayList<Empresa> empresasList = new ArrayList<Empresa>();
                for (DataSnapshot empresaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Empresa empresa = empresaSnapshot.getValue(Empresa.class);
                    empresasList.add(empresa);
                }

                if(empresasList.size() > 0)
                {
                    AdapterEmpresas adaptersubCat = new AdapterEmpresas(Empresas.this,empresasList,getApplicationContext());
                    listaEmpresas.setAdapter(adaptersubCat);
                }
                hideProgressDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando información...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DirectorioEmpresas2.class);
        objIndent.putExtra("id_categoria", id_categoria);
        startActivity(objIndent);
    }
```

Comment: El método onBackPressed no lo tienes que implementar. Con lo que haces, creas una nueva actividad, no vuelves a la anterior, la cual está creada en la pila de actividades. Y en la clase DirectorioEmpresas2 lo mismo. Mientras no destruyas la actividad, no tienes que volver a crearla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la Activity DirectorioEmpresas inicia la Activity DirectorioEmpresas2, no necesitas realizar esto,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DirectorioEmpresas.class);
    startActivity(objIndent);
}
```

Ya que abre mediante un Intent la Activity que en realidad esta Activa.

Si usas ese método, entonces finaliza la Activity que realiza el Intent mediante `finish();`, ejemplo:

```
...
...
startActivity(objIndent);
finish();
```

Comment: gracias, me funciono perfectamente

Comment: Excelente, saludos!